# Software to simulate mechanics of production line

Tags: mechanism, simulator

Is there any software where I can simulate production line elements (joints, motors, springs, actuators, movement)? For example I want to simulate mechanism to unwind paper from big roll to weld it later with bubble foil and finally make bubble foil envelope, mechanism will look like this:

[image]

I need it as simple as possible and preferably free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project looks promising http://gazebosim.org/.